# How do you properly modify a char array element in a 2D array using user input? Specifically for movie theater seating

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have been working on designing a seating chart in particular that mimics a movie theater seating with rows and columns using a 2D char array. I initialized the array with the character '#' to signify the seat is empty. However, I want to give the user the ability to choose a row and column to choose the seat they want and replace that element in the array to '*' to signify it is taken. The thing is I made a user input to so it "should" modify and update the seating chart with the taken seats, but instead it shows the seat as if it was never taken.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

//Global variable.
char seatingChart[15][30];

//Function prototype.
void theaterDisplay();

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int choice;
   int row;
   int col;

//initializing all elements in array with '#'.
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        seatingChart[i][j] = '#';
}

//Loop to let user input the seat they want.
while(true)
{
    //Calling function to display seats so user can decide.
    theaterDisplay();

    cout << "Enter row: ";
    cin  >> row;
    cout << "Enter col: ";
    cin  >> col;

    if(seatingChart[row-1][col-1] == '*')
    {
        cout << "Seat is taken.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        seatingChart[row-1][col-1] == '*';
    }

}

}

//This function is simply just to display the seats available.
void theaterDisplay()
{
cout << endl << setw(25) << "Seats\n";
cout << "\t123456789012345678901234567890\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    cout << "row " << (i + 1) << "\t";

    for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
        cout << seatingChart[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Id appreciate if any of you can figure out what is it I am doing wrong because I feel like it should work fine, but for some reason it is not overwriting '#' for '*' inside the array when user inputs row and column. Feel free to paste and run it. Hopefully my code is straightforward, if you need some clarification let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to point out that many theatres do not have a simple grid-layout of seating.  Many are curved, and rows are differing sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seatingChart[row-1][col-1] == '*';
```

should read

```
seatingChart[row-1][col-1] = '*';
```

Comment: I feel so dumb for not realizing I misused the operator for what I was not supposed to do and posting this. Thank you so much, you don't know how much trouble I went trying to figure it out. Cheers man! :)